# React Redux ... syntax error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react and es6 and i get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/MyUsername/Desktop/reactApp/main2.js: Unexpected token (7:12)

   5 |  switch(action.type){
   6 |          case "CHANGE_NAME": {
>  7 |                  state = {...state, name: action.payload}
     |                           ^
   8 |                  break;
   9 |          }
  10 |          case "CHANGE_AGE": {
```

I'm assuming it is an es6 syntax error i already set my webpack config for es6 like this:

```
query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
```

Comment: Try using ````[ ...state, name: action.payload ];````.

Comment: Yes, in ES6 it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Object spread is on staging 3 currently and not included in Babel presets 'es2015'.

To enable object spread you'll need the plugin

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Ref: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem, and solve it adding the plugin 'transform-object-rest-spread'!